# PHP modify hard dependency with reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
use AAA\BBB\Bar;
class Foo {
    private function hello() {
        ...
        $foo = new Bar(); 
        ...
     }
}
```

I want to modify the **Bar** hard dependency.

I can't extends the Foo class and rewrite the hello method, because, the code between the Hard Dependency changes frequently.

Is posible change the hard dependency like this:?

```
$newFoo = SomethingReflection("Foo");
$newFoo->changeUse("Bar", "\ZZZ\YYY\Bar");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot make any modifications to the `Foo` class? Such as adding an optional parameter to `Foo::hello()`?

Comment: This is not something reflections can do, no. This is actively changing parts of imperative code, which is something you should never ever be wanting to do in the first place. You'll have to rewrite that part of the code, plain and simple.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I can't change this, because it's a really important and big third party vendor